# What is the default implementation of JAAS in Websphere?

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere, jaas

I was wondering what is the default implementation of JAAS in Websphere ?

**For example:** In Websphere, when you create a JAAS credential for a DataSource, where is the credential stored ? I mean what kind of store it uses ie: RDBMS, LDAP, Plain text file ... etc. So there must be some kind of store to which JAAS api must be connecting to in order to retrieve a DataSource's credentials when needed for authentication in the apps.

Not sure if I should use the word **implementation** here.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Implementation" is the correct word.

WebSphere stores its entire configuration in a set of XML files (such as `server.xml`, `resources.xml` and so on) inside the profile directory. JAAS entries are stored there as well (with passwords encrypted of course).

Comment: Which means it is safe to say that the Default login store is XML and which is why JAAS is using its XML Service Provider Implementation module to connect to XML store.

Answer (score 4):

All you need to know about WebSphere Passwords is in [this Infocenter Note](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/tsec_protplaintxt.html).

In a word, WebSphere encodes passwords and store the encoded value in some XML file. The application server includes an encoder, but the decoder is on you. This encoding is not considered an appropriate password protection technique and there are [several ways to hack this](http://webspherehacks.com/blog/?p=5).

JAAS encoded password are stored here:

```
profile_root/config/cells/cell_name/security.xml
```

The full list of credentials and related XML files is listed in the first link of this answer.